# javascript not compiling in rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I recently updated to rails 6.0.2 everything works fine but as i was creating a new project i fined that the javascript folder has been moved from assest pipeline to the app folder. Am using a theme to create a simple one page site everything works fine except the javascript. I have placed all my javascripts file `app/javascripts/packs` and here is how am calling it on my homepage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/snap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery.prettyPhoto.init.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jQuery.headroom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/headroom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/script.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.video.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.slideanims.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.actions.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.kenburn.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.navigation.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.migration.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"></script>
```

here is my application.js

```
console.log('Hello World from Webpacker')
require("packs/bootstrap")
require("packs/headroom")
require("packs/jquery-migrate")
require("packs/jQuery.headroom")
require("packs/jquery")
require("packs/jquery.prettyPhoto.init")
require("packs/jquery.prettyPhoto")
require("packs/jquery.themepunch.revolution")
require("packs/jquery.themepunch.tools")
require("packs/owl.carousel")
require("packs/revolution.extension.actions")
require("packs/revolution.extension.kenburn")
require("packs/revolution.extension.layeranimation")
require("packs/revolution.extension.migration")
require("packs/revolution.extension.navigation")
require("packs/revolution.extension.parallax")
require("packs/revolution.extension.slideanims")
require("packs/revolution.extension.video")
```

but i still get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascript/revolution.extension.parallax.min.js"):
```

Answer (score 3):

if you have loaded all your js in application.js . Shouldn't it be sufficient to call

```
 <%= yield :javascript %>
```

in application.html.erb.
Another way you can place your js files in public/js/packs directory and access those file like

```
<script src="/js/packs/jquery.prettyPhoto.init"></script>
```

Comment: if this solution works for you,please accept this answer